# Flag-Options missing in Triage Queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, triage

While reviewing Triage I had [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/23781426) (now on hold) which is clearly *Too Broad* and therefore *Unsalvagable*. However, as you can see below, the flag-options were just missing from the menu.

[image]

I ended up flagging for moderator attention with a short description and a link to this thread as the *Spam*- or *Offensive*-Flag would have been incorrect. Was this what I was supposed to do? Is this a bug?

Comment: You couldn't flag too broad because the question was already closed

Comment: @NickA What is the question doing in Triage-Queue then?

Comment: You probably got into the triage queue after it was reviewed. Judging by the votes, it was closed from outside the queue. It's just a race condition

Comment: It would be better if you retract the mod-flag because it is going to be declined.

Comment: @MiXT4PE I agree with double-beep, retract your flag and move on, you reviewed correctly with unsalvagable, keep doing what you're doing

Comment: For future reference, if this situation happens again, just Skip it and let the system catch up on its own.